# Is it intentionally that php thinks there was some output after ob_end_flush() call?

Tags: php, output-buffering

This code:

```
ob_start();
ob_end_flush();

header('foo');
```

Throws warning

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent
```

while this:

```
echo '';
header('foo');
```

doesn't.

I don't see any significant difference between them.

So is this behaviour expected or not?

PS: php 5.3.2

Comment: Have you tried a more up-to-date version of PHP? 5.3.10 apparently doesn’t do that: http://codepad.viper-7.com/PBuzbY

Comment: @rynah: run `phpinfo()` there - it's `output_buffering 4096`

Comment: i did not get the error with php 5.3.6

Comment: @Amir: what `output_buffering` value do you have?

Comment: @zerkms, `output_buffering 4096`

Comment: @Amir: that's why you don't see the error. Turn it `off`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[My initial reaction](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/9160521#9160521) to this was "that's the behaviour I would expect" but it [turns out](http://3v4l.org/Zc83a) there are some subtleties hinging on the PHP version you are using.

First let's cover why my initial reaction was what it was, since (given that [you are using 5.3](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/9160672#9160672)) it does apply to your tests:

`ob_end_flush()` implicitly calls [`flush()`](http://php.net/flush), pushing the headers to browser regardless of whether any content has been generated.
`echo '';` on the other hand is basically a [NOOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP) - you asked the engine to do nothing, so nothing happens.

However, a little more investigation shows that the [`implicit_flush` option](http://php.net/outcontrol.configuration#ini.implicit-flush) for OB is in fact *off* by default, so this shouldn't in fact make any difference unless you have enabled the option explicitly.

Moreover, this behaviour is *not* seen before 5.2.2 or from 5.4.0+ - so my next port of call was to compare [this](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_3/main/output.c) with [this](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/main/output.c). Even if you can't read C at all, it should be plainly obvious that there is a huge difference between the output handling in 5.3 and 5.4 - a fairly substantial rewrite has happened.

Due to real-life commitments I have yet to pull it apart properly and find the relevant key code for this specific issue, but I will do so soon and expand on this answer when I have done so.

---

Summary:

- Depending on your PHP version and configuration, this may quite possibly be logical and expected behaviour.
- Heavy differences in PHP versions make this question have more that just one simple answer